# SQLalchemy query_cls for a specific query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I specify `query_cls` **only** for a one query? I tried to use `query.session._query_cls` and, of course, it doesn't work...

I want to perform something like this:

```
query = Session.query(MyModel)...
default_querycls_result = query.all()
custom_querycls_result = query.update_query_cls(CustomQueryCls).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new query object and copy `__dict__`

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
class CustomQuery(Query):
    pass

query = Session.query(MyModel)
default_querycls_result = query.all()

custom_query = CustomQuery(entities=[])
custom_query.__dict__ = query.__dict__.copy()
custom_querycls_result = custom_query.all()
```